# Unable to Start Production Profile in Jhipster Version 1.0.0

Tags: jhipster

Helo Everyone,

I have just take update of jipster to 1.0.0 but when i created project without webscoket i.e Atmosphere is not working on Production profile giving these exception while try to run Project on Production Profile Please Help Me.

```
[DEBUG] com.application.gom.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor
[DEBUG] com.application.gom.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registring JVM gauges
[INFO] com.application.gom.config.MetricsConfiguration - Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
[INFO] com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker - null [dev] [3.2.5] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
[INFO] com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker - null [dev] [3.2.5] Picked Address[192.168.1.11]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
[INFO] com.hazelcast.system - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] Hazelcast 3.2.5 (20140814) starting at Address[192.168.1.11]:5701
[INFO] com.hazelcast.system - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] Copyright (coffee) 2008-2014 Hazelcast.com
[INFO] com.hazelcast.instance.Node - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] Creating MulticastJoiner
[INFO] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] Address[192.168.1.11]:5701 is STARTING
[INFO] com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] Connecting to /192.168.1.12:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
[INFO] com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] 55994 accepted socket connection from /192.168.1.12:5701
[INFO] com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnection - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] Connection [Address[192.168.1.12]:5701] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
[WARN] com.hazelcast.nio.ReadHandler - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] hz.gomapplication.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[192.168.1.12]:5701, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
[INFO] com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] Connecting to /192.168.1.12:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
[INFO] com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager - [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] [3.2.5] 55995 accepted socket connection from /192.168.1.12:5701
```

Comment: did you solve it ? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The error you have has nothing to do with Atmosphere, but HazelCast.
It looks like you selected the HazelCast option, and that it can't create its cluster, because of an issue with host 192.168.1.12 -> this is probably a network error, do you have a firewall running?